# How to stop the flickering scrollbars and still get max screen sized canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, responsiveness

I'm trying to get my canvas element to take up the whole width/height of the document body, and have it resize when the body size changes (such as a cell phone going from portrait to landscape).

The canvas resizes as expected, but for some reason causes the scroll bars to "flicker" off and on.

```js
let dimensions = {
  w: document.body.clientWidth,
  h: document.body.clientHeight,
};

const log = console.log.bind(console);
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
let canvas;
let ctx;
let screenSizeObserver;
let initialized = false;

function initialize() {
  if (document.visibilityState === "visible" && initialized === false) {
    initialized = true;

    let c = document.createElement("canvas");
    c.id = "canvas";
    document.body.append(c);

    canvas = $("#canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    dimensions.w = document.body.clientWidth;
    dimensions.h = document.body.clientHeight;
    canvas.width = dimensions.w;
    canvas.height = dimensions.h;
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", initialize);
  initialize();
});

screenSizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
  //log(document.body.clientWidth);

  dimensions.w = document.body.clientWidth;
  dimensions.h = document.body.clientHeight;
  canvas.width = dimensions.w;
  canvas.height = dimensions.h;
});

screenSizeObserver.observe(document.body);
```

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background:
        linear-gradient(180deg,
            rgba(0, 191, 254, 1) 10%,
            rgba(252, 252, 252, 1) 100%);
}

canvas {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like changing the canvas to a Block level element instead of an Inline element will fix the flickering issue. It allows *exact* setting of the canvas element width/height to the body element width/height, removing the scrollbars entirely and still covering the entire viewable area.

```js
let dimensions = {
  w: document.body.clientWidth,
  h: document.body.clientHeight,
};

const log = console.log.bind(console);
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
let canvas;
let ctx;
let screenSizeObserver;
let initialized = false;

function initialize() {
  if (document.visibilityState === "visible" && initialized === false) {
    initialized = true;

    let c = document.createElement("canvas");
    c.id = "fui_canvas";
    c.style.display = "block";
    // css style display property MUST be set to "block" or it will cause an annoying flickering of the scroll bars off and on;
    // also, the width/height will be 17px over/under, and not the maximum exact pixel size of the body;
    document.body.append(c);

    canvas = $("#fui_canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    dimensions.w = canvas.parentElement.clientWidth;
    dimensions.h = canvas.parentElement.clientHeight;
    canvas.width = dimensions.w;
    canvas.height = dimensions.h;

    screenSizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
      dimensions.w = canvas.parentElement.clientWidth;
      dimensions.h = canvas.parentElement.clientHeight;
      canvas.width = dimensions.w;
      canvas.height = dimensions.h;
    });

    screenSizeObserver.observe(document.body);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", initialize);
  initialize();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background:
        linear-gradient(180deg,
            rgba(0, 191, 254, 1) 10%,
            rgba(252, 252, 252, 1) 100%);
}

canvas {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

Comment: Interesting note: after more testing, the flickering persists if the canvas has a border (as of Chrome Version 116.0.5845.179 (Official Build) (64-bit). Without a border it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a short of debouncing and set the width and height once the resize has done

```js
let dimensions = {
  w: document.body.clientWidth,
  h: document.body.clientHeight,
};

const log = console.log.bind(console);
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
let canvas;
let ctx;
let screenSizeObserver;
let initialized = false;
let shouldResize = true;

function initialize() {
  if (document.visibilityState === "visible" && initialized === false) {
    initialized = true;

    let c = document.createElement("canvas");
    c.id = "canvas";
    document.body.append(c);

    canvas = $("#canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    dimensions.w = document.body.clientWidth;
    dimensions.h = document.body.clientHeight;
    canvas.width = dimensions.w;
    canvas.height = dimensions.h;
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", initialize);
  initialize();
});

screenSizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
  //log(document.body.clientWidth);
  if (shouldResize) {
    shouldResize = false
    dimensions.w = document.body.clientWidth;
    dimensions.h = document.body.clientHeight;
    if (canvas) {
      canvas.width = dimensions.w;
      canvas.height = dimensions.h;
    }

  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    shouldResize = true
  }, 1000)

});

screenSizeObserver.observe(document.body);
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 191, 254, 1) 10%, rgba(252, 252, 252, 1) 100%);
}

canvas {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```